# Como solicionar a incompatibilidade do símbolo do menu mobile com alguns navegadores?

Tags: css, html5

O símbolo do menu mobile que utilizo não exibe em alguns navegadores pertencentes a alguns tablets que minha família possui.

```
<label class="menumobile" for="bt_menu">&#9776;</label>
```

**CSS**

```
label.menumobile{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  color:#fff;
    min-height: auto;
    background-color: #FF8922;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

 label[for="bt_menu"]{
padding: 5px;
background-color:#FF8922;
color:#fff;
text-align: center;
font-size: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente, a razão é que nenhuma fonte no sistema onde o navegador rodando contém a codificação para "☰"

As alternativas são:

- Use uma imagem em vez disso.
- Use uma fonte para download com `@font-face`. Isso pode significar que
  alguns megabytes precisam ser carregados no sistema do usuário.

Tente usar o `&#8801;` em vez do `&#9776;`, são parecidos.

Também podemos criar um ícone de hambúrguer / menu usando algumas coisas de CSS e HTML que funcionam bem em todas as versões dos navegadores sem fazer qualquer intervalo.

**CSS para ícones como:**

```
.hamburger-icon {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 19px 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.hamburger-icon span {
    width: 40px;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 5px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.hamburger-icon span:last-child {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

**E HTML:**

```
<label class="hamburger-icon">
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
</label>
```

Exemplo executando: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/kvxqtbht/)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2):

Um pequeno complemente para resposta de cima. 
Você poderia a [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io/), ela é leve,rápida e gratuita.